# multiprocessing with apscheduler

Tags: python-3.x, apscheduler

I have about 200 items to process and it is a job which continuously runs every second.

I tried the following code but it looks like it processes the number of items, matching CPU cores. My understanding that it is because of pool.map only schedules processes matching CPU cores and because of BlockingScheduler does not return.

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import datetime
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler


def process(number):
    scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(timer, 'interval', seconds=1, args=[number])

    scheduler.start()


def timer(number):
    print(f"{datetime.datetime.now().time()} {number} - completed processing. ")


def run(number_to_process):
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
        pool.map(process, number_to_process)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    number_to_process = range(1, 200)
    start_time = time.time()
    run(number_to_process)
```

So, I tried the following code. It looks like it is processing all 200 items. My question is: is it making optimum use of CPU or there are any side effects as I am creating 200 processes here?

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time
import datetime
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler


def process_number(number):
    scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(timer, 'interval', seconds=1, args=[number])

    scheduler.start()


def timer(number):
    print(f"{datetime.datetime.now().time()} {number} - completed processing. ")


def run(number_to_process):
    processes = []

    for number in number_to_process:
        print(number)
        p = Process(target=process_number, args=(number,))
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)

    for process in processes:
        process.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    number_to_process = range(1, 200)
    start_time = time.time()
    run(number_to_process)
```

Answer (score 0):

200 process is a small number. You can check the maximum number of process your system support by running the below command:
cat /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max
It gives the maximum number of process that system can support.

To check if CPUs are efficiently used, run htop command while running your application

Also, you can try enable Affinity for more efficient usage of cores.
Please refer to this link for more details on affinity,
https://docs.python.org/dev/library/os.html#os.sched_setaffinity